# Parallel web requests in Python (request.get and BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, get, beautifulsoup

I have a simple Python script that loops through a dictionary, where the keys are url links. I have to extract some info from each link and store the info into another dictionary. The code below is the first part of the function and the code seems to work as expected. 
But it opens only one link at time, while I think I might get some improvement in run time if I do this in parallel. Do you have any suggestion how I can achieve this in a simple way in Python?

```
def updater(local):
    links = myItems['links']
        for link in links.keys():
            page = requests.get(link)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
            newsoup = soup.find("div", {"id": "overviewQuickstatsBenchmarkDiv"})
            rows = newsoup.findAll('tr')[1]
            counter = 0
            date = ""
            for td in rows.findAll('td'):
                counter += 1
                if td.contents[0] == 'Date':
                    date = td.text.replace("Date", "")
                elif counter == 2:
                    pass
                elif counter == 3:
                    price = re.findall("\d+\.\d+", td.string)[0]
```

Here's what I tried using multiprocessing (but I cannot get any result and the code seems to run doing nothing):

```
    def read(url):
        result = {'link': url, 'data': requests.get(url)}
        print "Reading: " + url
        return result


    def updater(local):
        links = myItems['links']
        pool = Pool(processes=5)
        results = pool.map(read, links.keys())
            for link in links.keys():
                # need to read the results and store data into a dictionary
```

Comment: You can try `grequests` or `threading` or `multiprocessing`

Comment: this is the perfect case for using [`scrapy`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy)

Comment: Do you mind showing me how to change the code?

Comment: @opt As Adam suggested this can be done using the methods specified above but to add on top of it, Python has a GIL (global interpreter lock) you can google it, it's a slow language, I'd suggest just doing this in Java or C. 
Even with the methods above it will still be slow (if you care about the speed) but the biggest issue is that you wait for the request-response (a lot) and then do your processing, instead of doing the requests and the processing on separate threads, cores... This is just some insight into your issue to get you rolling, hopefully, someone can show us some code.

Comment: I am trying with multiprocessing but no success. I added the code above. Hope you can spot the issue. Thanks.